# Zoom image is not showing

Tags: android, eclipse, zooming

I am trying to click on the link (as below) but nothing happens! It should open big an zoom-able picture

hotel.xml (this is a second file)

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/hotel01small"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="45dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="Picture"
   android:textSize="10sp"
   android:textStyle="italic" />
```

i'm pasting everything to see what's wrong with it

hotel01small.xml

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/hotel01small"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:scaleType="matrix"
   android:src="@drawable/hotel01" />
```

H01.java

```
package com.som.balem;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class H01 extends Activity {
    ImageView imageDetail1;

 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
 PointF startPoint = new PointF();
 PointF midPoint = new PointF();
 float oldDist = 1f;
 static final int NONE = 0;
 static final int DRAG = 1;
 static final int ZOOM = 2;
 int mode = NONE;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.hotel);
  setContentView(R.layout.hotel01small);

  imageDetail1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hotel01small);

  imageDetail1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()  {


   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    System.out.println("matrix=" + savedMatrix.toString());
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
     startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
     mode = DRAG;
     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

     oldDist = spacing(event);

     if (oldDist > 10f) {
      savedMatrix.set(matrix);
      midPoint(midPoint, event);
      mode = ZOOM;
     }
     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
     mode = NONE;

     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     if (mode == DRAG) {
      matrix.set(savedMatrix);
      matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
        event.getY() - startPoint.y);
     } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
      float newDist = spacing(event);
      if (newDist > 10f) {
       matrix.set(savedMatrix);
       float scale = newDist / oldDist;
       matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
      }
     }
     break;

    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

    return true;
   }

   @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
   private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
   }

   private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
   }
  });   
 }
}
```

H01First.java

```
package com.som.balem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class H01First extends Activity {

    Button hotel01small;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hotel01small);
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.som.balem"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PageOneHotel"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".H01"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".H01First"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help!

Comment: Why are you calling setContentView twice ?

Comment: I tied it from root, it worked, but it gives me nothing when I put a link for it, it has been two before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an OnClickListener to your button to open the second screen when you tap it, otherwise it won't do anything:

H01First.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class H01First extends Activity {

    Button hotel01small;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hotel);

        hotel01small = findViewById(R.id.hotel01small);
        hotel01small.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // open up the second activity
                Intent i = new Intent(H01First.this, H01.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Also, it's a good idea to use different ids for all your widgets, otherwise you can get conflicts and it makes the code more confusing.

If you want the H01First Activity to display first, change your Manifest.xml to put the intent-filter inside the HO1First definition:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.som.balem"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".PageOneHotel"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".H01"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".H01First"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still not functional, I didn't know where to put the OnClickListener !

Comment: add it to H01First.java

Comment: Forgive me for saying this, it's on "hotel01small.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()" and I don't know what to do else!

Comment: What happens when you open up the H01First activity and click the button? It should open the H01 activity. Also, change the setContentView() line in H01First.java to setContentView(R.layout.hotel);

Comment: I am assuming that you want to be able to click the button and open up the zooming image. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm adding, removing and the button still not active, so yes!

Comment: In your manifest.xml, try moving the intent-filter section with MAIN And LAUNCHER to the H01First actvitity

Comment: I tried to put it here and there, it didn't work :/ can you please write it for me if you don't mind!

Comment: It works fine but the problem is, it's making the button as a first page and there is a first page already, I moved the .PageOneHotel which is before it, and the the .H91 in the manifest like before, but it's still working as the same page, thought, it's not